# Lose focus on Embededd/Flash element/tab in Firefox

Tags: javascript, flash, firefox, focus, keystroke

Without [AutoHotkey and Firefox -unfocus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/unfocus/) since it's involved in operating another program and it doesn't work on linux and without [Restore Window Focus After Flash](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restore-window-focus-after-fla/) addon since doesn't give you control over flash tabs.

Did anyone succeeded in implementing this `gBrowser.selectedTab.unfocus();` method and bind it to a keystroke in Firefox v3.6 ?

I've also tried (based on the addon above)

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName("EMBED").length == 0) {
  return;
}

if (document.activeElement.tagName == "EMBED") {
      document.activeElement.blur();
}
return;
```

But it doesn't work.

Also tried this JS code binded to a keystroke:

```
var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].
  createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
var process = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"].
  createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
var args = ["-unfocus"];
file.initWithPath("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
process.init(file);
process.run(false, args, args.length);
```

Still no go.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I am the author of unfocus extension.

Generally as far as I now you cannot simply bind keystroke in Firefox to unfocus plugin, because Firefox doesn't have focus. Plugin have full keyboard focus, so to unfocus plugin you *must* use external application.
That's the reason for creating such extension. It's the only way with the most simple implementation.

I run linux and almost every Window Manager I know support keybindings to commands. AutoHotkey is only one of the ways to achieve this on Windows. Because of this I always seen this extension as far more simple for Linux/BSD crowd.

Bind a keystroke to `firefox -unfocus` command.

#### If you use metacity (default WM of gnome):

```
gconf-editor -> / -> apps -> metacity -> global_keybindings and keybinding_commands
```

#### If you use kwin (kde):

http://maketecheasier.com/configure-custom-shortcuts-in-kde/2009/09/28

novell.com/coolsolutions/qna/11619.html

#### If you use xfwm (xfce):

`Keyboard Settings -> Shortcuts`

#### If you use openbox (lxde):

http://urukrama.wordpress.com/openbox-guide/#Key_mouse

Note that I don't use previously mentioned WM-s and DE-s, I just searched a little.
If you use tiling wm you should already know how to bind a keystroke.